# TeamCity : JMeter Test run throws an error about ~ Result item must include asserted result

Tags: jmeter, teamcity

Encountering the below error while Running a JMeter test from TeamCity.

Result item format must included asserted result. Format: startTime responseTime testName...
Found[1567618705330,1335,01_Launch_InfiniteJP_01_jp,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,985,470,1,1,https://infinite-uat.daimler.com/Jp/,1334,0,1061]

Everything works on my machine and even on team city, the html report gets generated. Just that test fails with the error and marks it Failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [How to Run JMeter Tests with TeamCity for Continuous Integration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-tests-teamcity-continuous-integration/) article:

> **Important!** The JMeter TeamCity plugin expects the results file to be in a specific non-default format, the most important requirements being:
>
> 1. The metrics need to be separated by TAB characters
> 2. The first line needs to be column headers

So you need to amend [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) by adding the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. I have added the above lines to Jmeter.properties files, but now have updated the user.properties as well. Will revert if this helps as currently the change is not reflected. I will restart and check :P <Classic jmeter move>